# Python Eliminar datos de una lista dentro de un diccionario formato JSON

Tags: python, diccionarios

Intento eliminar datos de un JSON pero lo unico que consigo es un diccionario vacio al filtrar
Este seria parte del codigo

```
     data = {
            "name": "Name",
            "description": "Collection",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "trait_type": "Background","value": "Blue"                    
                },
                {
                    "trait_type": "Body","value": "Naked"                    
                },
                {
                    "trait_type": "Clothes","value": "Red"
                },
                {
                    "trait_type": "Mouth","value": "Naked"
                }
                
            ]
      
       
        for atributos in data['attributes']:
                
                if atributos['value']  == 'Naked':
                    atributos.clear()
```

Y el resultado al ejecutar me crea este JSON

```
        "name": "Name",
        "description": "Collection",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "trait_type": "Background","value": "Blue"                    
            },
            {},
            {
                "trait_type": "Clothes","value": "Red"
            },
            {}

        ]
```

Lo que no consigo es eliminar {} de los datos borrados :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear no elimina el diccionario, solo borra su contenido, de ahí que te queden diccionarios vacíos. Si querés eliminar de la lista los diccionarios bajo x condición, vas a tener que crear una nueva lista a partir de la anterior la cual no contenga los diccionarios a eliminar.

```
data["attributes"] =  [attributos for atributos in data['attributes'] if(atributos['value']  != 'Naked')]
```

Nota: Estoy usando una comprensión de listas. En este tutorial explican muy bien que son: https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/comprension-de-listas-y-otras-colecciones/

También se puede modificar la lista original, pero es más lio.

Answer (score 0):

El método `clear()` simplemente remueve el contenido de un diccionario. No lo elimina; lo deja vacio.

Aunque hay métodos para eliminar elementos individuales en una lista o diccionario, usarlas mientras se recorre dicha lista o diccionario se presta para resultados imprevistos en ejecución.

La manera normal de recorrer-y-filtrar es construir una lista o diccionario nueva, que inicialmente parte vacia. En el recorrido, vas agregando los elementos que deseas conservar:

```
filtrados = []
for atributos in data['attributes']:
    if atributos['value'] != 'Naked':
        filtrados.append(atributos)
data['attributes'] = filtrados
```

Con eso la nueva lista reemplaza a la antigua.

#### Demo

```
import pprint

data = {
    "name": "Name",
    "description": "Collection",
    "attributes": [
        {
            "trait_type": "Background", "value": "Blue"
        },
        {
            "trait_type": "Body", "value": "Naked"
        },
        {
            "trait_type": "Clothes", "value": "Red"
        },
        {
            "trait_type": "Mouth", "value": "Naked"
        }
    ]
}
print("Datos originales:")
pprint.pprint(data)
filtrados = []
for atributos in data['attributes']:
    if atributos['value'] != 'Naked':
        filtrados.append(atributos)
data['attributes'] = filtrados
print()
print("Datos filtrados:")
pprint.pprint(data)
```

produce:

```
Datos originales:
{'attributes': [{'trait_type': 'Background', 'value': 'Blue'},
                {'trait_type': 'Body', 'value': 'Naked'},
                {'trait_type': 'Clothes', 'value': 'Red'},
                {'trait_type': 'Mouth', 'value': 'Naked'}],
 'description': 'Collection',
 'name': 'Name'}

Datos filtrados:
{'attributes': [{'trait_type': 'Background', 'value': 'Blue'},
                {'trait_type': 'Clothes', 'value': 'Red'}],
 'description': 'Collection',
 'name': 'Name'}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Filter

Falta una respuesta usando *filter()* que su definición es precisamente obtener un subconjunto a partir de una condición.

Funciona básicamente con dos argumentos:

1. función que verifica si un elemento de un iterable cumple la condición (*True/false*).
2. Iterable en el cual se quieren verificar los elementos que cumple la condición

El resultado es que obtienes los elementos que cumplen la condición, en este caso **value!="Naked"*

#### Código

En código:

1. condición:

```py
lambda x: x['value']!="Naked"
```

2. iterable:

```py
data['attributes']
```

Como *filter()* devuelve un iterable tipo *filter* has de convertirlo a lista:

```py
data["attributes"]=list(filter(lambda x: x['value']!="Naked",data['attributes']))
```

#### Resultado

El resultado sería:

```
{'attributes': [{'trait_type': 'Background', 'value': 'Blue'},
                {'trait_type': 'Clothes', 'value': 'Red'}],
 'description': 'Collection',
 'name': 'Name'}
```

Comment: Yo no uso filter ni map ya que habitualmente requieren uso de funciones lambdas y eso no es tan agradable a la vista. Pero es solo una opinión, es bueno ver otra alternativa.

Comment: @Dante S. Creo que eso es lo maravilloso de la programación "Poder generar soluciones de diferentes manera" me gusto mucho la solución al igual que la tuya.